# Azure Function Queue Trigger: Queue message dropping even before it got picked by Azure function Intermittently

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-queues

I have a Queue trigger Azure function which is triggered whenever a queue msg appears in Azure Queue Storage.

My work flow is:
A user may schedule a task which needs to run after a few days at a particular time (execute at time)

So I put a message in azure queue with visibility timeout as the time difference b/w current time and the execute at time of that task.

So when the msg is visible in the queue it gets picked up by the azure Function and gets executed.

I'm facing an intermittent issue when the queue message is supposed to be visible after a few days(<7 days). But somehow it got dropped/removed from the queue. So it was never picked up by the function, and that task still shows pending.

I've gone through all the articles I have found on the internet and didn't find solution to my problem.

The worst part is that it works fine for a few weeks but every now and then the queue messages (invisible ones)
Suddenly disappears. (I use azure storage explorer to check number of invisible messages)

Comment: It sounds like your use case fit exactly to Durable Functions :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#monitoring

Comment: Is it ending up in the poison/dead letter queue?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use Service Bus instead of Storage queues? I would guess that ASB would be far more reliable for such an use case.

Comment: No they're not ending up on poison queue. And I haven't explored Service Bus yet.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing your time calculations correctly? Local time vs UTC, etc?  Make sure you're using UTC throughout for all dates and times.

Comment: Yes Im doing time calculations correctly, I've checked the logs, the visibility timeout was set correctly.

Comment: another instance of this function running elsewhere consuming the message? Enable diagnostics logs in Portal to log all events (dequeue/publish/...) on your Q. Reproduce the behavior. Post diagnostic logs.